# While trying to loop through all users, all the hidden table data is displayed for each user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I am trying to list all the users that have registered on my site, but I am getting all the table data for each user on my view page.

User_controller.rb :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @users = (current_user.blank? ? User.all : User.find(:all, :conditions => ["id != ?", current_user.id]))
  end

    def show
      if params[:id].nil? && current_user
        @user = current_user
      else
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
      end
      @cereal = current_user.cereals.build if signed_in?
      @cereals = @user.cereals.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def first_time
      if params[:id].nil? && current_user
        @user = current_user
      else
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
      end
  end

    def edit
        if params[:id].nil? && current_user
            @user = current_user
        else
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
        end
  end

    def profile
        @username = params[:id]
        @friends = current_user.friends || []
        @title = "User Profile for #{@username}"
        @user = User.find_by_username(@username)
        @users = User.all :conditions => ["id != ?", current_user.id]
  end 

end
```

User.rb(model)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Amistad::FriendModel
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  has_many :cereals, dependent: :destroy

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:login]


  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :login, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar, :firstname, :lastname, :phone, :urlname
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  attr_accessor :login

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
        where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
      else
        where(conditions).first
      end
    end

            def update_with_password(params={})
        current_password = params.delete(:current_password)

        if params[:password].blank?
          params.delete(:password)
          params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
        end

                result = if params[:password].blank? || valid_password?(current_password) 
          update_attributes(params)
        else
          self.attributes = params
          self.valid?
          self.errors.add(:current_password, current_password.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
          false
        end

        clean_up_passwords
        result
      end
    end
```

Views/users/index:

```
= @users.each do |user|
    %li
        = user.username
```

Anyone have any idea why when I open the index page for users, everything from the user table in the database is being displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is after a very quick glimpse of your code, but off the top of my head try removing the = from your index view.  It should be

```
- @users.each do |user|
```

Comment: Not a problem, just an FYI: - sign is used when you don't expect that line to output anything to the view, = is used when you do expect it to